# How can you send location based push notifications to all android/ios devices that enter range of an IOT device

Tags: android, ios

I would like to send a location based push notification to all devices that enter a range of some kind of IOT device.

for example I would have a device which sends push notifications to any phone that enters range of the device. Similar to location based push notifications.

How could you do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what BLE beacon technology does.

It requires an app<sup>*</sup> on the device to tell the phone to listen for the broadcasts and then act accordingly when it receives one.

Beacons have a normal range of approximately 10m

<sup>*</sup> An app is required because otherwise this would be a truly horrific way to force advertising on people. Before Google gave up on the idea (Eddystone Beacons) Android had a reasonably nice compromise where the beacons would push a URL pointing to a website that would appear in the notification area (without out any noise or vibration).

Comment: Thanks hardillb, i really need a way to do this without an app. Is there a way of doing it phone to phone or device to phone using blue tooth when very near by? Like a prompt for the user to pair to the device without needing any additional app and then seeing a short message with a URL to anothor page?

Comment: No, as I said anything like that would be incredibly intrusive from an advertising point of view.

Comment: I'm looking at this page, wouldnt this fast pair do that? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/announcing-fast-pair-effortless.html

Comment: No, you still need an app to understand what ever message was sent over the Bluetooth link.

Comment: If it were possible, you would be constantly bombarded by messages all the time from all locations you walk through or even nearby. Thankfully this is not possible. What is your usage scenario?